# Disappearing code in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am having an amazingly strange issue.
I have two applications I am working on. For about 2 weeks I haven't worked on one of them because I was working on the other one.

Now when I return to my other one, I find things missing. The application works fine it just miss thing I did previously.

How does Android Studio saves the code that I am writing and how is it possible for it to disappear without a trace?
I am speaking of whole sections and functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that you changed those files and saved them. Then you may be lucky to find the changes in the local history of Android Studio.

Right click on the file that you want to recover and choose `Local History -> Show History`

It should show the history of the file.

Also you need to pay extra care and use version control SVN/Git in the future. I prefer to use bit bucket as it is free.

Comment: Sadly the local history goes just 4 days back for me. I am sure I have done a lot of changes - I have created new layout and linked it to my code - I have build it, ran it on emulator. Now the code is like it was before that. I exclude any "external" interference as it is not like deleting/replacing 1-2 files ...

Comment: Then look for another version of the project on your disk

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what could be the cause of that, but have you considered using [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system? That's how you make sure your code doesn't disappear.

I strongly suggest getting yourself acquainted with [Git](https://git-scm.com/).